# How to build a "block taxonomy tagging feature"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-blocks

First, I apologize the title is so vague. Its hard to explain what I want to accomplish. Anyhow, I want to build a template that requires a pool of nodes (Content Type A) to be presented along side the main content of a page (Content Type B). This Content Type A could be seen as a box if you like. As you create a new page (Content Type B), would it be possible for a list of nodes (Content Type A) that would allow an easy checkbox system to show on the page? I know of nodequeue, but it would really be inefficient to create a nodequeue for every page created. Going the taxonomy route would be slightly difficult as well because every new pool content (Content Type A) would need a new taxonomy term for it to be checked individually. Is there a simple way to display a list of these pool of boxes to be presented along with main content?

That was long-winded. I really appreciate all your responses.

Thanks.

---

Edit: I just re-read my question and it doesn't seem to read very well. I will use an example of an article with a list of "side adverts" on both sides of the article. After creating a node pool of "side adverts" can I simply create a new article node and have a list with checkbox system (where I can enable / unable) to show the chosen "side adverts" with the article?

I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think your requirement is not that difficult.

In the Content Type B create a Node Reference Field that links to Nodes of type A only. Set the number of values of the Node Reference field to 4, 5, unlimited (etc) depending on many nodes you want linked from B to A.

Now you can create a View which will list all the Content Type A nodes when viewing a node of Content Type B.